# Overflow of div's on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen this in many documentations on GitHub. The div on right seems to overflow with the left as shown in the image.

[image]

Every time i change some thing like CSS of tables or containers it works fine. But what is the root cause for this and both have z-index as 0, how come they overlap each other.

[**Link to documentation**](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-icons). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how z-index is related to the two element overlapping. It just sets the stacking/priority order and the element which comes after in DOM is shown above the other element. BTW I don't see the problem in the demo page you linked.

Comment: I guess your css having problem

Comment: @ManojKumar do you see a scroll bar at bottom?

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz It mostly uses bootstrap just want know where the issue is

Comment: It looks to be because they are nesting containers as far as this example is concerned. See [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Comment: @vanburen makes sense for this case, Can you pls check this http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ it has only container but has same problem